# ReflectionException in Symfony application

Tags: symfony

i deployed my symfony application on my server and it works fine in dev mode but in prod mode i have this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class
>   Sharincook\MessagerieBundle\Entity\Sharincook\MessagerieBundle\Entity\Message
>   does not exist

and if i try to clean cache with putty i have this error :

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in ....app/console

so i don't have any ideas
thanks

Comment: First guess: Different PHP versions locally and in prod?

Comment: i found the solution : `php5.5 app...` instead of `php app...` thanks